# f-string throws a SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I get invalid syntax error when I try to iterate over a list of names saved in names.txt file. Here's the syntax

```
names = []

with open("names.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        names.append(line.rstrip().capitalize())

for name in sorted(names, reverse=True):
    print(f"hello, {name}")
```

The error I'm getting looks like:

```
$ python name_read.py
  File "name_read.py", line 8
    print(f"hello, {name}")
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Which Python version are you using? `python --version`

Comment: f strings were introduced in Python 3.6, you must be using an older version.

Comment: I'm using a venv with python 3.10.5

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The python version was somehow changed to 2.7 causing the issue. I reconnected to the venv with v 3.10.5 and is now working